# Добавить декоратор к функции

Tags: javascript, ооп

Используя прототип класса Addition добавить декоратор к функции add, дающий возможность логировать ее вызов
При этом результат выполнения add должен быть как и в оригинале, но дополнительно при вызове выводить в консоль 'called'
Менять изначальную функцию, класс или созданный объект нельзя.

```
 class Addition {
     constructor (num) {
         this.num = num;
     }

     add (...nums) {
         const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
         return this.num + nums.reduce(sum);
     }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, это звучание задания, а какие попытки вы уже предприняли?

Comment: Addition.prototype.add = function (...nums) {
    console.log('called');
    const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
    return this.num + nums.reduce(sum);
}    тесты проходят. но не такое решение мне нужно. Я хочу понять как то сделать с переопределением  функции через прототип.

Comment: так Вам надо переопределить метод `add` в прототипе или не переопределять?

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать строго задаче, можно получить следующее:

> Используя прототип класса Addition добавить декоратор к функции add

1. нужно взять текущую функцию из прототипа `var add = Addition.prototype.add`
2. сделать для нее обертку

   ```
    Addition.prototype.add = function(...) {... /* вызов add */ ...}
   ```
3. в обертке добавить логирование

   ```
    Addition.prototype.add = function(...) { console.log('called'); /* вызов add */ }
   ```

---

Чтобы вызов `add` работал как раньше, достаточно при вызове установить контекст в текущий элемент передав `this`.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
class Addition {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  add(...nums) {
    const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
    return this.num + nums.reduce(sum);
  }
}

var a = new Addition(5);
console.log(a.add(1, 2, 3))

var add = Addition.prototype.add;

Addition.prototype.add = function(...nums) {
  console.log('called');
  return add.call(this, ...nums);
}

var b = new Addition(2);
console.log(b.add(1, 2, 3))
console.log(a.add(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// декоратор
const decorWithLog = func => function(...args) {
    console.log('called');
    func.call(this, ...args);
}

class Addition {
     constructor (num) {
         this.num = num;
     }

     add (...nums) {
         const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
         return this.num + nums.reduce(sum);
     }
}

// переопределяем метод add на декорированый метод
Addition.prototype.add = decorWithLog(Addition.prototype.add);
```